# Gitlab CI, how to get a container host name, started with docker-maven-plugin

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-maven-plugin

I'm setting up an integration testing environment for my Spring Boot Java application. So I'm spinning off a PostgreSQL database using `docker-maven-plugin`, which my application is supposed to call into.

This setup works ok when running `mvn verify` on my local system, but on the GitLab CI runner, is failing, because the PostgreSQL hostname doesn't match anymore.

My question is, how can I get the hostname of the database container in the CI pipeline?

My plugin configuration looks something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${docker.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-it-database</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>postgres:9.6.14</name>
                        <alias>it-database</alias>
                        <run>
                            <ports>
                                <port>it-database.port:5432</port>
                            </ports>
                            <wait>
                                <log>(?s)database system is ready to accept connections.*database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                <time>20000</time>
                            </wait>
                            <log>
                                <prefix>POSTGRESQL-TEST</prefix>
                                <date>ISO8601</date>
                                <color>blue</color>
                             </log>
                         </run>
                     </image>
                 </images>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
         <execution>
             <id>remove-it-database</id>
             <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>stop</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Eventually, I will have to pass that database hostname in my `application yaml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgresql
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<db_host_name_here_once_i_get_it>:${it-database.port}/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    schema: classpath:schema-postgresql.sql
    data: classpath:data-postgresql.sql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    initialization-mode: always
```